# Issues with geom_dumbbel plot giving me multiple points instead on single points

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggalt

[image]

My dumbbell plot is giving me multiple points on my graph and I am wondering why. I assumed I am supposed to be getting a single point. I have tried editing the parameters but to no avail. it is making it difficult to add other aesthetics. I will appreciate any help.

```
    data10 <- structure(list(GROUP = c("LLL", "LLL", "LLL", "LRL", "LRL", "LRL", 
"RLR", "RLR", "RLR", "RRR", "RRR", "RRR"), conditon2 = c("Midline_Ret", 
"No Midline crossing_Ret", "Midline crossing_Ret", "Midline_Trans", 
"No Midline crossing_Trans", "Midline crossing_Trans", "Midline_Trans", 
"No Midline crossing_Trans", "Midline crossing_Trans", "Midline_Ret", 
"No Midline crossing_Ret", "Midline crossing_Ret"), Trial_type = c("retention", 
"retention", "retention", "transfer", "transfer", "transfer", 
"transfer", "transfer", "transfer", "retention", "retention", 
"retention"), Training = c("left", "left", "left", "right", "right", 
"right", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right"), 
    N = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), MovementTime_102 = c(1940.625, 
    2200.234375, 1950.078125, 1623.59375, 2266.875, 2608.4375, 
    1649.21875, 1690.390625, 3128.660714, 2018.75, 1701.40625, 
    2505.703125), MovementTime_104 = c(1601.875, 1658.046875, 
    1573.839286, 1435.15625, 2013.359375, 2302.109375, 1390.859375, 
    1616.71875, 2399.765625, 1410.625, 1336.40625, 1684.53125
    ), Pathlength_102 = c(2.8680385, 3.872267719, 2.808966672, 
    3.184808844, 3.450548063, 2.779296859, 3.057751688, 2.823023969, 
    3.831920395, 2.991207031, 2.790851078, 3.276254563), Pathlength_104 = c(2.65516175, 
    2.945664516, 2.568061634, 3.017285625, 3.408170609, 2.625024781, 
    2.655326156, 2.628399641, 2.975724094, 2.636576609, 2.661606391, 
    2.782565766), NormalizedJerk_102 = c(2060.157118, 2981.812369, 
    2089.925187, 1391.973644, 3900.411917, 4015.516784, 1411.201689, 
    1853.413926, 6830.819063, 2310.589311, 1340.465366, 5617.967587
    ), NormalizedJerk_104 = c(1092.701687, 1508.285476, 1269.670456, 
    914.3836443, 2335.718672, 2563.167235, 847.952528, 1394.847247, 
    3915.019566, 1023.170254, 765.2752941, 1705.629422), AveResultantVel_102 = c(2.021215719, 
    1.994460031, 1.789839578, 2.449869109, 2.037483406, 1.198650234, 
    2.374258766, 2.162818172, 1.467132962, 2.101220406, 1.983419094, 
    1.595565484), AveResultantVel_104 = c(2.317185313, 2.193130625, 
    2.113643324, 2.822947859, 2.213037, 1.311399453, 2.39646225, 
    2.113288797, 1.481807047, 2.644351188, 2.54589975, 2.014750766
    ), EndpointError_102 = c(1.62285542, 2.05362611, 2.27036917, 
    1.57970041, 1.83768956, 2.14219202, 1.374642, 2.03515938, 
    2.58900025, 2.28107478, 1.64171472, 2.13489883), EndpointError_104 = c(0.979220453, 
    1.477764016, 1.621229031, 1.239002656, 1.404618047, 1.796644641, 
    1.01018125, 1.593606016, 1.672676594, 1.483629813, 1.503123406, 
    1.370374047)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(GROUP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), conditon2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Trial_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Training = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), N = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MovementTime_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), MovementTime_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Pathlength_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Pathlength_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), EndpointError_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), EndpointError_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))


    ggplot(data10, aes(y=conditon2, x=MovementTime_102, xend=MovementTime_104)) +
  geom_dumbbell(size=3, color="#e3e2e1",
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Change in Movement time ms")
```

Comment: You probably have duplicates for condition2. Do you need to facet by GROUP?

Comment: No, each level in condition2 is unique

Comment: No, there are duplicates _overall_. It's only unique _within_ the `GROUP` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got duplicates for `condition2`. You probably want to facet on the `GROUP` variable.

```
ggplot(data10, aes(y=conditon2, x=MovementTime_102, xend=MovementTime_104)) +
  geom_dumbbell(size=3, color="#e3e2e1",
                colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue",
                dot_guide=TRUE, dot_guide_size=0.25) +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Change in Movement time ms") + 
  theme_minimal() +
  facet_grid(~GROUP)
```

[image]

---

Required packages:

```
library(ggalt)
library(ggplot2)
```

Comment: With the facet grid, it works but once, I take it off I get the doubles points

Comment: Because `condition2` is only unique _within_ the `GROUP` variable. ;)

Comment: oh got it, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

I started using this platform I dont have enough reputation to use comments.
Your problem lies here `data10$conditon2`. You have multiple conditions in that column make them unique or group them.

You columns must be unique.

```
unique(data10$conditon2)
```